# Can't get generated keys to increase by 1

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm using Java and JPA for ORM.

Initially I was defining entity keys like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

but that resulted in ids that were growing pretty fast and in unpredictable ways (...19,20,22,1003...1007,1014,1015,2004...)

which seems to contradict [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2) which state that "The simplest key field is a long integer value that is automatically populated by JPA with a value unique across all other instances of the class when the object is saved to the datastore for the first time. Long integer keys use a @Id annotation, and a @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation"

So I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/org/datanucleus/test/SequenceExamplesJPA.java?spec=svn473&r=473) unit test and I switched to the way it was done there:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
```

which migrated fine after updating some GQL statements, but I'm still seeing keys increasing by 1000 every time.

Should I be using GenerationType.TABLE?  Or should I have been using IDENTITY on a Long rather than a Key field?

I'm hoping to get some definitive answers before I keep changing this in my live (beta) app.  Unfortunately all schemes I've used so far in the dev env result in contiguous keys so really no way to test out new approaches except by deploying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generation.TABLE is not implemented for GAE JPA, since doesn't fit well with the datastore architecture. IDENTITY makes more sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really hard to do contiguous keys on App Engine.  The docs never stated that the auto-generated keys are contiguous - only that they will be unique.

The simplest solution on app engine is to design your keys so that you don't need them to be contiguous.  Given the way BigTable is designed, if you did have contiguously incrementing keys, you'd likely have some perf bottlenecks whenever a tablet needs to be split under the hood.

Comment: I guess I should be more specific, I'm not necessarily looking for a contiguous guarantee, just that it not increment 10s, 100s or even 1000s at a time.

Comment: Either way, the easiest thing to do is to allow for that in your design.  Otherwise, you need to assign your own keys.  In that process, you need to guarntee that each key you use is unique (or else you'll overwrite your own data).  Because different requests hit different server instances, you'll need some way to synchronize to make sure the same key isn't generated on two server instances at the same time.  Most of the time, all you really need is a unique key anyways.

Comment: I'm guessing that, as an optimization, each instance reserves ahead 1000 key values. But instances may be short-lived for many reasons. You're probably seeing an indication of instance restarts. And that's working as designed and intended.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith that makes a lot of sense, but doesn't appear to be the case.  I just added 6 entities in quick succession, while watching my instances go from 1 to 4, and the ids all were increased by 1000.  So that tells me that perhaps yes, it's reserving 1000, but no, it is not the case of getting a new instance (since i did not see 5 or more new instances serving those add requests).  So I'm inclined to think it's an issue with Datanucleus or how I have it configured that it does reserve 1000, uses 1 and then discards the rest.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're doing 6 operations and getting 4 instances, enabling multi-threading might be a good idea.

Comment: @minimo Your app is running on multiple instances; each one has a different range of IDs to assign from. As dragonx says, IDs are not guaranteed to be sequential, or incrementing, just unique. Why do you (think you) need a compact ID range?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I have `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` and Idle Instances set to auto/auto, but I've always seen this crazy instance-creation behavior and seen others describe the same and how changing the Idle Instances settings only makes it worse. Pending Latency is set to 5s-10s

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm not really looking for strictly sequential or even incrementing, just to not blow 1000 every time.  Mainly I'm just thinking ahead, I don't want my system to get to a billion comments one day and already my ids be at a trillion (13 digits)  If each instance indeed reserves and (mostly) uses 1000 as dragonx guessed I would leave it at that, but as I pointed out my quick experiment indicates that the same instance is still assigning in 1000 increments.  BTW the [site](http://www.commentous.com) is for  discussion/social, comments are its core, will be shared, pasted, etc.

Comment: If you're using the default IDs, the skipped IDs aren't lost, they'll get used up eventually.  If you don't need sequential or even incrementing, then this is not a problem.  And even if your IDs get to a trillion, the 64-bit long can do a few thousand times that.

Comment: @dragonx. That makes sense, I guess you're right I'm making too much out of nothing. Thanks for your answer.